# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a Laptop with i3 12Gen Processor, 4GB RAM and 256GB SSD Hard

Tags: 22.04, hard-drive, ssd, laptop, hardware

If the Ubuntu 22.04LTS OS is installed on a Laptop with i3 12Gen Processor, 4GB RAM and 256GB SSD Hard, will it functioned properly with out any slowness...?

Comment: It will work, but the ram will be a bottleneck. Use Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead.

Comment: CPU and SSD is fully ok, but depending on what you intend to to RAM may get thigh. Recommended choice is to use Lubuntu instead of Ubuntu or any of the other derivates. Lubuntu is the "slimest" of the *buntus available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/986878/) and [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)